# How do I write custom model validators for my plugin that refer to other fields?

Tags: plugin-development, validation, models

I'm looking at this guide to writing custom validators:
https://experiencehq.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-5-custom-validators

However, this only allows code that refers to the current field.  The comparison validators exist so I know it's possible.  I want to do a CVV and credit card number validator that check against the credit card type, and also make some fields conditionally required.

In this example only the attribute itself is referred to:

```
public function validateUsername($attribute)
{
    $value = $this->$attribute;

    if ($value && strtolower($value) == 'spartacus') {
        $message = Craft::t("No, I'm Spartcus!");
        $this->addError($attribute, $message);
    }
}
```

How do I refer to another field in the model in my validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I can just refer to the other field name:

```
public function validateUsername($attribute)
{
    $value = $this->$attribute;
    $otherFieldsValue = $this->otherField;

    if ($value && strtolower($otherFieldsValue) == 'spartacus') {
        $message = Craft::t("No, I'm Spartcus!");
        $this->addError($attribute, $message);
    }
}
```